# Drupal 7 - Search box

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am using drupal 7's standard search box setup and was wondering how i would be able to change it and lose the actual search button. I am pretty new to using drupal so any kind of help or insight would be really helpful.

Here is the php code that I am using:

```
<?php print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('search_block_form')); ?>
```

and it currently comes out looking like this:

[image]

I was wondering if there was any kind of way to manipulate the code to make it drop the search button and perhaps add in a text to the search area grayed out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either add a placeholder via javascript, or you could use the [Custom Search module](https://drupal.org/project/custom_search) and use the block to place it correctly.

Comment: Any tips on how to use the custom search module. The documentation seems a bit confusing for me at least...

Comment: Just enable it, add a block to your region, configure the block.

Comment: Sorry! yes it did! Thanks!